# Zimbra - Domain on different IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, zimbra

What I'm trying to do is to set zimbra properly. I'm using on my server multiple domains. All on one IP address.

But for one new domain, I want it to be visible differently. What I want to achieve is to prepare special IP address for this one domain on zimbra server, and configure zimbra to use it for sending and receiving e-mails.

So - postfix must be listening on this IP address.

If I connect to this IP, I should have HELO with my "new" domain

And if I send e-mail from zimbra - it should be sent from this new IP.

So what I did:

I tried `VirtualIPAddress` on zimbra (just to be proper everywhere - this will not help me - I know - it's for webmail certs only, until SNI will be deployed in Zimbra 9)

And tried configure domain like this:

http://forums.zimbra.com/administrators/58056-how-set-different-outgoing-ip-each-domain.html

So I've got sender dependent regexp to:

```
/@domain\.com$/ domain_com
```

and in master.cf.in i've got:

```
    domain_com unix - - n - - smtp
    -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1 (my new IP)
    -o smtp_helo_name=domain.com
    -o smtpd_banner=domain.com ESMTP
    -o syslog_name=postfix-domain_com
```

So what I've got here - Seems like Zimbra 8.6.0 is not loading this file, since there is no errors (It should be I think - Since default zimbra is listening on all ports - there should be conflict)

So how should I properly configure zimbra to use separate IP address for just one domain?

Also - Will this files be archived while update of zimbra? Or they will be overwritten while updating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Let clear some side-question before proceed into main question:**

> Will this files be archived while update of zimbra? Or they will be overwritten while updating?

Yes, Zimbra will overwrite master.cf.in and all of zimbra predefined configuration templates.

> So what I've got here - Seems like Zimbra 8.6.0 is not loading this file, since there is no errors (It should be I think - Since default zimbra is listening on all ports - there should be conflict)

The configuration above is modify postfix behaviour to set another **outgoing instance** (not incoming instance). So it doesn't need listen to any port. And so there are no other error, if any error happened zimbra (or postfix) will stop working. To verify that zimbra has used new configuration, see `master.cf` file.

---

**Now for the main question**

> How should I properly configure zimbra to use separate IP address for just one domain?

You can use postfix specific feature called Postfix Multiple Instance. It's heavily documented in postfix [official docs](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html). So you can try that. There other resources  in this Unix.SE question: [postfix multidomain myhostname configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177770/postfix-multidomain-myhostname-configuration/179175#179175).

You can use that tutorial but you won't achieve this feature: *If I connect to this IP, I should have HELO with my "new" domain*. You only achieve your outgoing email goal:  *if I send e-mail from zimbra - it should be sent from this new IP.*

---

**For side note**

The downside of *using control-panel like zimbra* is lose some flexibility in the original packages. In your case here, you wont' able to use 100% postfix functionality because it'll limited by Zimbra specific configuration. For example: in current release, zimbra doesn't yet support Postfix Multi Instance feature to achieve your full goal.

Comment: Thank You very much. I know how to configure postfix with multi instance - I'm using it somewhere else, but with zimbra, I'm pretty sure it will be a real problem. OK. I Will just start on other virtual server another instance of zimbra with new IP, and that's all. Thank You